# Fatal error: Uncaught Error:

Tags: php

tengo este error Fatal error: **Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function remove_junk() in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\valire.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\valire.php on line 5**,y no le hallo la solución xD este es el codigo:

```
include('valietc/conex.php');

$name = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['name']));
$last = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['apellido']));
$user = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['username']));
$iden = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['ci']));
$phone = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['te']));
$email = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['email']));
$address = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['dire']));
$contra = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['pass']));

if(isset($_POST["butt"]))
{
   $sqlgrabar = "INSERT INTO usuario(username,password,nombre,apellido,identificacion,.telefono,correo,direccion)
   values ('$name','$last','$user','$iden','$phone','$email','$address','$contra')";
   
   if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqlgrabar))
   {
       echo "<script> alert('Usuario registrado con exito: $nombre'); window.location='index.html' </script>";
   }else 
   {
       echo "Error: ".$sqlgrabar."<br>".mysql_error($conn);
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: Pues no existe la función `remove_junk()` en *valire.php* ni en *valietc/conex.php*. Por otro lado la línea `$sqlgrabar = "INSERT INTO..."` tiene un `.` antes de `telefono`. Adicional, los datos en `values()` no corresponden al orden de los identificadores en `usuario()`, por ejemplo: el identificador `password` está de segundo pero en `values()` el dato `$contra` está de último.

Comment: ¿No sería más acertado llamar a la función `remove_junk()` (que tendrás que definirla o crearla porque no es estándar de PHP) antes que a `DB::escape()`? En caso contrario podrías estar eliminando los caracteres de escapado y su trabajo habrá sido inútil. Además, para evitar mensajes de advertencia de índices no definidos, deberías agregar esas asignaciones **dentro** del bloque `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por lo que entiendo estás queriendo evitar caracteres raros en esos campos, no sería más fácil usar la función preg_replace por ejemplo:

```
$res = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $string);

$string = "Th*()is 999 is <<>> a ~!@# sample st#$%ring.";
$res = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $string);
echo $res;
```

Y el resultado sería: Thisisasamplestring

Comment: Ok gracias por responder, el ```remove_junk()``` lo puede reemplazar por ```$_POST```?

Comment: Pues no, porque remove_junk() es una función que elimina caracteres si entiendo bien, y $_POST es la variable donde se reciben los elementos enviados por método post de un formulario, son cosas muy diferentes, uno procesa datos y el otro solo los trae del formulario

Comment: Ok muchas gracias

Comment: Formato con función no definida: `$name = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['name']));`
Formato simple: `$name = $_POST['name'];`
Formato con eliminación de caracteres indeseados: `$name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $_POST['name']);`

Comment: Bien lo probare

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te dice ese error es que la función "remove_junk()" no existe en el archivo actual ni en los incluidos. Puedes agregar la siguiente función para evitar el error:

```
<?php

function remove_junk($text) {

  $text = strip_tags($text);
  //$text = htmlspecialchars_decode($text);
  //$text = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","",$text);

  $RemoveChars[] = "([,.:;!?()#&%+*\"'])";
  $ReplaceWith = " ";
  $text  = preg_replace($RemoveChars, $ReplaceWith, $text);

}
?>
```

Tu códigio debe quedar asi:

```
<?php

include('valietc/conex.php');

function remove_junk($text) {
  $text = strip_tags($text);
  return preg_replace("([,.:;!?()#&%+*\"'])", "", $text);
}

$name = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['name']));
$last = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['apellido']));
$user = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['username']));
$iden = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['ci']));
$phone = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['te']));
$email = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['email']));
$address = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['dire']));
$contra = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['pass']));

if(isset($_POST["butt"]))
{
   $sqlgrabar = "INSERT INTO usuario(username,password,nombre,apellido,identificacion,.telefono,correo,direccion)
   values ('$name','$last','$user','$iden','$phone','$email','$address','$contra')";
   
   if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqlgrabar))
   {
       echo "<script> alert('Usuario registrado con exito: $nombre'); window.location='index.html' </script>";
   }else 
   {
       echo "Error: ".$sqlgrabar."<br>".mysql_error($conn);
   }
}

?>
```

Para mas información visita este sitio https://www.zimplicit.se/en/knowledge/php-remove-junk-characters